# Indexing all pages of a website in Google

Tags: 6

I use Google CSE on my website, which contains upwards of 5000 stories. Naturally, I would like all of this content to be indexed in Google. Many of these stories will not be linked elsewhere on the site... can they still find their way into Google's search index?

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer to your Q, but have you considered trying to increase/improve the internal links on your site? It's not normally a good thing from an SEO POV to have lots of content with no inbound links. Some taxonomy pages and maybe a _related content_ block could perhaps help.

Comment: Sure but the thing is, many of these stories are archives, I want people to be able to find them, but I can't link directly to each and every one of them.

Comment: If the issue's purely one of time (ie there's too much content to manually alter) then you can still try an automated approach, eg. a related items block that uses the node contents to 'guess' which nodes are related to one another. Even a simple chronological paged feed might be better than nothing. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: So xml sitemap wouldn't help index unlinked nodes?

Comment: It will, it will! I was really just making an additional comment about improving your site's SEO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [XML sitemap module](http://drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) will generate a file which can be submitted to google, and other search engines to tell them about all of your content.

Comment: OK thanks - do you think that would be enough to index all of my nodes?

Comment: If you install and enable the proper sub-modules, you should be able to get all of your orphaned pages into the sitemap.